# Why is my HTML Bootstrap pill not showing up?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is probably extremely simple but I can't figure it out. I am trying to have a pill show up as it appears in the [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-pills), however it is simply showing up as basic html text with a bullet next to it. I've looked through the documentation and other similar questions asked here but can't seem to figure out what is wrong.

My code:

```
<div>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What it shows up as:

- Home

Included in my header is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'personal/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type = "text/css"/>
```

Using Bootstrap 3.3

Comment: Did you include Bootstrap's stylesheet with `<link>`?

Comment: Is it only the pill? Do other elements work? Are you using BS3 or 4?

Comment: @JREAM I'm using BS 3.3

Comment: @AndrewLi I think so, very new to html/css/bootstrap, what I have in my header I've updated in my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a CSS problem. It is difficult to help you without your full code. Are using local files or do you load bootstrap from CDN?
Make sure Bootstrap is loaded correctly (CSS & Js).

Try replacing your link code with the following to see if it works

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

If it does, your link has a problem.

Comment: That worked! But I'm curious why would my link have been the problem, I downloaded bootstrap and was using the distribution locally on my computer. And also, is maxcdn officially from boostrap? Is this safe to use?

Comment: What language are you using? Pure HTML?

Comment: I am using this with Django

Comment: If you have a developer tool in your browser, can you check that the file is being loaded? If you use chrome, you can right-click -> inspect -> Console to check errors or Network to check if your file was loaded

Comment: Okay it turns out I was being dumb and left out a directory in my file path, and I accepted this answer because replacing my code with yours led me to realize what I had left out, thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help!